# Use a handler to make retrofit calls

Tags: android, callback, retrofit

I am trying to create a handler to make my api calls using retrofit.
My call work and I get a response, but I would like to know what would be a best practice to return the response.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
public class ApiHandler{

    private static String username = "myUsername";
    private static String sessionID = "mySessionID";

    public static ObjectResponse getObjects(String id){
        ClientApi.getApiClient().getObjects(new ObjectRequest(username, sessionID, id), new Callback<ObjectResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void success(ObjectResponse ObjectResponse, Response response) {
                //Request succes

                /*I would like to pass the ObjectResponse from the success method to the getObjects method to be able to return them*/
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                //Request failure
                ///TODO
                System.out.println(error.getResponse().getStatus());
            }
        });

        //I would like to return the ObjectResponse here
        return null;
    }   
}
```

Then I just call from my fragment: `myObjectResponse = ApiHandler.getObjects(id);`

My problem is that when the success() method is called in the callback, the getObject() method already ended and I'm not able to return the response.

I saw that I could use an eventbus (otto) to achieve that but I'm not sure how that works or if it even is the best way to do that.

So how could I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found my answer.
Using otto I just need to send the objectResponse to the bus as followed:

```
public class ApiHandler{

    private static String username = myUsername;
    private static String sessionID = mySessionID;

    public static ObjectResponse getObjects(String id){
        ClientApi.getApiClient().getObjects(new ObjectRequest(username, sessionID, id), new Callback<ObjectResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void success(ObjectResponse objectResponse, Response response) {
                //Request success
                BusProvider.getInstance().post(objectResponse);
                /*I would like to pass the ObjectResponse from the success method to the getObjects method to be able to return them*/
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                //Request failure
                ///TODO
                System.out.println(error.getResponse().getStatus());
            }
        });

        //I would like to return the ObjectResponse here
        return null;
    }   
}
```

And then in my fragment, register as a receiver:

```
    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        //Unregister the fragment from the bus provider
        BusProvider.getInstance().unregister(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        //Register the fragment to be able to receive events through the bus provider
        BusProvider.getInstance().register(this);
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onObjectResponse(ObjectResponse objectResponse){
        System.out.println("We did it!!!");
        //Do what you want with your object!
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Before EventBus, an interface was required as a private member of the `ApiHandler` class (in your case). Now on success, you call your unimplemented method of your interface.

You implement this method somewhere in your UI, and you call `getObject()` to run in the background. Once the method is successful, it will trigger your interface method which you have implemented in your UI along with the `objectResponse` to play around with.

EventBus has quite similar concept except that it is a central (or singular) and works in a channel/subscribe manner. Try to use Eventbus + Retrofit + any dependency injector to ease your life.